# iOS viewController and detailViewController flow/design

Tags: ios, parsing, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

1. Where/how/when ought I initialize my second parser?
2. What is the best configuration of views/viewControllers for what I describe?

Here's the deal:

I have a tableViewController. I have it populated with data from a parsing class that initiates in the appDelegate method, applicationDidFinishLaunching... This class runs through an XML file I created.

Each item populating the tableViewController are associated with a URL, which will be parsed as a row is selected inside the tableViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method (is this the right thing to do?).

The results of the second parsing are to populate the detail view with titles of the items from the selected url of the second parsing. I would not be writing this question if it were that simple. I need to be able to pick an item populating the detailview and drill to another detailview showing the details of that item.

Im using nibs

This is not a discussion question:

1. Where/how/when ought I initialize my second parser?
2. What is the best configuration of views/viewControllers for what I describe?
3. Is there anything glaring I must know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

1.)parse data as soon as tableviewcell is selected then once finished load detail view with results. (con can slow interface down)

2.) load detail view and then parse data and populate details as data becomes available (con loads details view with no data and makes user wait)

So both options make the user wait but only one slows the interface down...

I think option 2 is the choice everyone will recommend.